# What is wrong in my set of differential equations of a projectile throw?

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I aim for using these differential equations to get y[t],x[t] and max range of projectile. I don't know if my physics is wrong or the code is wrong

```
  DSolve[
     {
      y'[0] == v0*Sin[a],
      y[0] == 0,
      m*y''[t] == -m*g,
      m*x''[t] == 0,
      x[0] == 0,
      x'[0] = v0*Cos[a]
      },
     {x, y}, {t, 0, 20}]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You had a syntax error. It should be `==` and not `=`. It is also better to break things out and write the ODEs on separate lines, and the ICs on separate lines, than to combine them - much easier to read and maintain. And since you are using `DSolve`, there is no need to fix the time span:

```
ClearAll[x,y,t,a,m,v0]

ode  = { m*y''[t] == -m*g, 
         m*x''[t] == 0 }

ic   = {y'[0] == v0*Sin[a], 
        y[0]  == 0, 
        x[0]  == 0, 
        x'[0] == v0*Cos[a]}

DSolve[ {ode, ic },  {x[t],y[t]},  t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you had done the above, you would have more easily spotted the syntax error also.

Comment: and  a max range of projectile: `Maximize[{1/2 (-g t^2 + 2 t v0 Sin[a]), Sin[a] > 0, v0 > 0, g > 0, 
  t > 0}, t]`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I dont understand the output. Wouldn't finding y==0 be better?

Comment: @Ralnor. Sure yes.:)